# Buildozer initiation issue in Ubuntu as 'command not found'

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to convert a kivy .py file into .apk using buildozer in ubuntu. I have been following this person's tutorial:

https://kivyspacegame.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/tutorial-how-to-build-python-for-android-with-ubuntu-and-buildozer/

However, I am stuck at the stage at

```
buildozer init
```

Resulting in error.

```
command not found
```

Similar issue is seen here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/_uCnOC8fdPo. But it doesn't have a solution. I checked cython and buildozer installations using 'pip freeze" and going into python and type 'import cython' and 'import buildozer', they didn't give me any error message.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer) you go, there are installation instructions. How did you install it actually? Try calling buildozer with python?

Comment: No you misunderstand my explanation. I am not trying to call buildozer in python. I am testing if the installation is correct by going into python > import buildozer to see if there is any error message.

Comment: I can confirm that this works just fine on Ubuntu 16.04. You'll need to provide more detail about exactly how you installed, because that method works fine (and it worked in 15.10, 15.04, probably earlier versions but it's not like I'm keeping track of this).

Comment: I used `try` because it was meant to tell you to try calling `buildozer init` from python(like python -m pip and so on), therefore it'd tell you if you installed it and you just don't have it in path or something, or you basically failed to install it at all and (re)installation is necessary. Or, some dependency is missing, but this shouldn't be an issue as buildozer gets that stuff itself.

Comment: This is the first time I am using linux, but I noticed there is some slight difference in the command line of installing buildozer from that tutorial and the guide suggested by KeyWeeUsr, I tried reinstalling it using the latter step, and now it seems to work just fine (spec file created), not sure why, but I am happy. Thanks Guys.

Comment: Although I got a "cython not found please install it" error when I run "buildozer -v android debug". I don't think cython or buildozer was installed properly from the first tutorial (maybe it's just my comp setting). Any suggestion?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install cython`

Comment: Now got "Java compiler (javac) not found, please install it" error, I tried 'sudo apt-get install javac' but got a 'unable to locate package javac' error

Comment: buildozer uses python-for-android to build APKs. Install these dependencies (on 16.04 use openjdk-8-jdk instead of openjdk-7-jdk): https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#dependencies

Comment: If you need more help, please join our [IRC channel #kivy on freenode](https://kivy.org/docs/contact.html#irc).

Comment: It seems to be working now after I have installed your suggested dependencies, much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @KubiK888, even if this is an old resolved issue, I would suggest creating an answer with the fix and accepting it as the answer to help anyone else having this problem

Answer (score 3):

it is already an older thread but, try this, if you have the problem today either. Just simply tiping this in the terminal..

> git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer
>
> cd buildozer
>
> python setup.py build
>
> sudo pip install -e .

and now u can type->

> buildozer init

etc..

p.s.
sorry for my English :D <3

Comment: Hi JR_
By reading the comments, it seems that the issue was that a few dependencies were missing. Furthermore, if someone does not explicitly need the Python 3 build of `buildozer`, the [recommended](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer#installing-buildozer-with-python2-support) method of installation is with `pip`

Comment: Just had to use `python3 setup.py build` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I tried to get out of it.

First uninstall buildozer :

```
pip3 uninstall buildozer
```

Then clone buildozer git :

```
git clone <link>https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git</link>
cd git_directory_new_made
```

Now in terminal go to root :

```
sudo su
enter password:your password here

python3 setup.py install
```

Go out of terminal and then reopen it.